# library not found for -lBolts

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode6, bolts-framework

I keep getting this error and have no idea how to fix. I've been stuck for days. I am using Parse to build this app and tried adding it with a pod. here is the error I am getting:

```
Ld /Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Intermediates/PixelFrontEnd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PixelFrontEnd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PixelFrontEnd normal x86_64
cd /Users/gerbonilla/Xcode/FrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.3.sdk -L/Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/gerbonilla/Xcode/FrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd/Pods/Parse -F/Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/gerbonilla/Xcode/FrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd/PixelFrontEnd -filelist /Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Intermediates/PixelFrontEnd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PixelFrontEnd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PixelFrontEnd.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -undefined dynamic_lookup -lBolts -lParse -lParseLib -lParseUI -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Intermediates/PixelFrontEnd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PixelFrontEnd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PixelFrontEnd.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -lsqlite3 -lz -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework Parse -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework Photos -framework Bolts -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Intermediates/PixelFrontEnd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PixelFrontEnd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PixelFrontEnd_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/gerbonilla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PixelFrontEnd-fuxewjczxiwihfairfbnkgdzbktq/Build/Intermediates/PixelFrontEnd.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PixelFrontEnd.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PixelFrontEnd
```

> ld: library not found for **`-lBolts`**
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use `-v` to see invocation)

Comment: The post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322907/1084174 resolved it for me

Answer (score 26):

Try to open your project using the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj` one.

Comment: I had the same problem with Flutter and this answer worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.

I've removed -l"bolts" from **Other Linker Flags** and set the platform to iOS 7.0 in the podfile. Then Clean -> Build. This worked for me.