# ld: library not found for -lBolts using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, bolts-framework

everybody

The problem that I am having is that I can't compile my app because I got the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have my XCode project configured to use cocoapods and this is my list of pods:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'XCDYouTubeKit', '~> 2.4.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
```

This is the output of the command `pod install`:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Installing Bolts (1.5.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.8.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.8.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.8.0)
Installing Google (1.0.7)
Installing GoogleAnalytics (3.14.0)
Installing GoogleNetworkingUtilities (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.0.3)
Installing GoogleUtilities (1.1.0)
Installing Parse (1.10.0)
Installing ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.9.1)
Installing ParseTwitterUtils (1.9.1)
Installing ParseUI (1.1.7)
Installing XCDYouTubeKit (2.4.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 10 dependencies from the Podfile and 15 total pods installed.
```

Things that I have tried:

- Clean and rebuild
- Exit xcode, clean and rebuild
- Delete all pods and re-install, clean and rebuild

Comment: The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322907/1084174) worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I had **two** problems:

1. The first problem was that I was building my original `YourApp.xcodeproj` Xcode project file.

   According to [`react-native`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk):

   > From now on open `YourApp.xcworkspace` instead of `YourApp.xcodeproj` in Xcode.

   So I had to switch to the new `YourApp.xcworkspace` generated by Cocoapods on `pod init` (or whatever generated it).
2. The README of `react-native` project doesn't mention that if you have previously added Facebook SDK into `YourApp.xcodeproj`'s `Frameworks` folder according to the step **4. Add the SDK to your Xcode Project** of [Facebook SDK for iOS - Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) tutorial, then you should remove those references, because Cocoapods will pull the FB SDK code into `Pods` folder, so you no longer need to reference FB SDK separately. Otherwise, Xcode tries to build according to the settings and instructions of the Cocoapods, but finds FB SDK which has binaries that are "not a `dylib`".

   Eventually, your `Frameworks` folder should have the only `libPods-YourApp.a` file.

   Clean, then build the project. It should work.

Comment: After a dark rabit hole of update an old app, this came up. Your post saved me a lot of time! I wish I could vote this up 10 more times.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this way:

- Delete `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock`
- Run `pod install`
- On `Pods` project of Xcode, on every pod target, set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No`
- Clean and build again

Comment: Where do I find `Build Active Architecture Only`? A screenshot would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Eye - Here's a screenshot for Xcode 7.3: http://i.imgur.com/7GpNoMA.png. A textual description: It's under Build Settings > Architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I was integrating `MFSideMenu` in my demo app and getting same error.
Solution work for me is below

**Build phases -> Link Binary With Library -> add new** -> then **select** `libXYZ.a`  from workspace (in my case its `libMFSideMenu.a`) -> **add** it. Clean project and buils again

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to re install pods with below commands from `Podfile` directory,

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

And then build after clearing **deriveddata** folder

If it does not work follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322907/1084174)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

1. Removed `-l"bolts"` from **Other Linker Flags** `(Project -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags)`
2. Have a clean build

NB: If you can't find it easily you can search in Workspace,

[image]