# Been getting ld: library not found for -lBolts while using xcworkspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Hello here is my `Podfile`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.4'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'APP' do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'JVFloatLabeledTextField'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'RKDropdownAlert'
pod 'LGAlertView'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'CardIO'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'DZNPhotoPickerController/Editor'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'MGInstagram'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'TOCropViewController'

end

target 'APPTests' do

end
```

I'm receiving the error

> ld: library not found for -lBolts
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've tried clean and build. no luck. I'm also using the `xcworkspace`
and I've also deintegrated pods many times and did `pod install` again. still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `pod update`?

Comment: I have answered to this in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36947791/556678. There are two steps for the solution.