# Xcode + Crashlytics: Trouble adding new UDID to existing profile

Tags: xcode8, provisioning-profile, crashlytics, udid

**Scenario**

Xcode is managing my provisioning profiles and it's done well so far. I'm adding a UDID for a tester yet crashlytics continually complains about the app not having the correct UDID for the tester which is where it prompts me to take a file that lists the user's UDID which I already put it. For kicks I copy/pasted the id and developer.apple.com said the device already exists.

*Steps I took:*

- log into developer.apple.com
- go to certificates, identifiers & profiles
- select devices > iPhone
- click + sign and add name w UDID, save device
- click provisioning files > development
- click the profile I want then Edit
- Devices: select all
- "Download" then double click the profile which opens xcode

I repeated this process multiple times occasionally mixing up the selected devices (worked years ago). Also updated profiles via Xcode's preferences > account tab.

**Build Steps**

- Product > Archive kicks open Crashlytics
- Click Distribute on prompt
- Prompt for incorrect / missing UDID

**Question**

How can I figure out what is going on here?

#Xcode8.2.1.8C1002

** EDIT **

I've found that Xcode is using the auto generated iOS Team Provisioning Profile instead of the one I originally created in the web portal. Seeing as how the auto profile inherits from the web one I created, I'm going to try to get the auto generated profile to recreate itself hopefully pulling in the new UDID.

- Xcode > Preferences
- Accounts
- Select Apple ID (top left)
- Select Team (bottom right)
- click View Details (bottom right)
- One by one, right click and delete all provisioning profiles
- Click "Download All Profiles" (bottom left)
- You may need to wait and click "Download All Profiles" a few more times with 5-10 second intervals.

I'm in NY so once QA wakes up I'll verify if this worked or not.

Comment: VErify the profile used for the app with (i) icon next to the drop-down of General Tab (Profile selected by automatic provisioning). Also, you can leave the tedious task to see UDID from dev account always. The app is compiled and passed as IPA so rename it as .zip and extract. then in payload right click and say show package contents. In that go to the embedded.provisioningprofile file and copy to desktop.

Run this command on terminal $security cms -D -i <profile path here>

You will see all the UDID Listed here in xml node <ProvisionedDevices>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was ultimately fixed by following this chain:
[Been getting ld: library not found for -lBolts while using xcworkspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459777/been-getting-ld-library-not-found-for-lbolts-while-using-xcworkspace)

## The Problem

This all hinged around an old `FacebookSDK`. When updating to the new `FBSDK*Kit` make sure you remove any old files resembling `FacebookSDK` otherwise you may run into this same issue.