# ld: library not found for -lBolts

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I had a Objective C project that was working fine and I decided to install Citrus Payment SDK via Cocoapods that SDK was wrote in Swift Language. I ran  pod install after cocoapods installed my podfile look like this,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' platform :ios, ‘8.0’ use_frameworks! target 'MyApp' do pod 'GoogleMaps' pod 'Google/SignIn' pod 'FBSDKCoreKit' pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' pod 'FBSDKShareKit' pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7' pod 'FGTranslator' pod 'SpeechKit' pod 'Braintree' pod 'SVPullToRefresh' pod 'IQKeyboardManager' pod 'CitrusPay', '~> 4.1.2' end
```

and now I'm getting this error:

```
  ld: library not found for -lBolts, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked for all missing frameworks and I open the project by using the .xcworkspace file. Already tried to clean the project or alt + clean the project and deleted the derived data in Xcode. I would post the build options but I don't know which are important for the problem. How can i fix the issue.Please, help me find the solution, Thank you for your help :)

Comment: please install cocoa pods for lBolts cause your  Citrus Payment SDK  having dependancies on that.

Comment: The post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322907/1084174 resolved it for me

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Podfile and verify that the platform ios is 8.0.

You can also do a `pod repo update', then`pod install`.

Which version of Cocoapods are you using ? `pod --version`

Check also your `Podfile.lock` to check every Pods version and Cocoapods.

After setting everything properly if it's doesn't work you can also try a `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` again.

Make sure to clean your project, and close Xcode and re open it.

I'm sure it will help you to find the issue.

**EDIT:** So the project is in Objective C and the library is in Swift right ?

Then add this to your Podfile, at the end :

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Change Swift version according to your needs.

Try looking around your build settings, main target (not project) :

- Always Search User Paths -> NO

Comment: I tried this but still the error not solve and i remove platform ios 8.0 but this also not worked..I dont know how to solve this..@Murloc