# IOS - How to Fix the "ld: library not found for -lBolts" Error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've got this annoying error for number of days now:

[image]

I've tried:
Deleting pods folder & pod file & pod.lock file & .workspace file and reinstalling pods again.
removing all library search paths in pods.xconfig file

this is my pod file :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'PersonalizedAdConsent'
pod 'Highcharts', '~> 6.1.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'

end
```

This is my problem, If you need any other indications or code about my issue, feel free to leave me a comment and I'll edit the question

Comment: The post https://stackoverflow.com/a/58322907/1084174 resolved it for me

Answer (score 5):

Try to run following commands in Terminal (in your project's folder):

```
pod deintegrate // removes all pod related configurations from your project
rm Podfile.lock //removes the saved reference to the pods
pod install // reinstalls the pods
```

Clean your project (In Xcode: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)

And finally make sure you compile the same target from which the error originates (You should be able to see the target it originates from within the issue navigator <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>)

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, the 3 commands + cleaning the project , I still get the same somehow , this is going to drive me crazy

Comment: how do I know if it is coming from the target MyApp?

Comment: Look at the issue navigator(cmd+5) or the build messages (last tab)

Comment: try removing DerivedData - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: i removed derivedData  and restarted xcode several times with no success

Comment: do you get an error and can still run on that target? or are you unable to compile right now?

Comment: I am unable to compile , it is an Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Comment: If you are using swift, you should include the line `use_frameworks!`

Comment: And if that doesn’t help, I would roll back to the last time it worked and see what changed