# react native and fblogin - ld: library not found for -lBolts

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I'm get
So i tried the solution posted [ld: library not found for -lBolts using cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257951/ld-library-not-found-for-lbolts-using-cocoapods/36947791#36947791) but still haven't be able to get things to work.  I'm using the `xcworkspace` file, tried uninstalling and reinstalling my pods but still not working.  Can anyone give me another solution to try ?  The one thing i did notice however is in that other solution posted above I still have multiple files under my Frameworks directory, and not just a single `libPods-YourApp.a` file